# Parallel current limiters, ballast resistors and transistor matching

Tags: transistors, bjt, current-limiting

Are ballast resistors (R17, R8 and R5) required when using parallel current limiters as show below?

[image: 3x current limiters in parallel]

I found it hard to find working examples on the internet with values already present to tweek around with.

So here is a link to the full circuit in LTspice XVII: https://pastebin.com/NakdA45N Just download the file and remove the .txt at the end, or copy the content to a .asc file.

Comment: Too long-winded for me to read. Basic answer to your first line is yes.

Comment: Yes, it was very convoluted. I removed almost everything to make the important part easier to find. Thank you for pointing it out rather than down-voting it.

Comment: Why do you use three in parallel? To share current? Or is it supposed to be some sort of "either-or" limiter?

Comment: To share the current. The super caps being charged have a max current of 5A, each limiter can handle ~1.5A due to heating, and would take ~38 seconds to charge with only one such limiter. With all 3 its down to ~13.5 seconds and is much more convenient to the end user.

Comment: Have you contemplated to make just one current limiter which can take the full 5 A? Otherwise, you reasoning is fairly sound but you should be able to simulate the max difference between channels you can get in transistor parameters and find worst case scenario for your paralell branches.

Comment: Yes, but 5A @ 58V will mean burning away 290 watts, so its easier to manage less at multiple points. The transistors gets very expensive as well, the TIP142 i have looked at can handle 125W (@ 25c fixed Tc, so less..), i have seen transistors in the 200-300W range but they cost 10x more.

Comment: Makes sense. Where in Sweden are you?

Comment: We also looked at switching instead, we have an inductor inline between our power source and the super caps, but the switchers that use this inductor are not connected in a way where we can use them for inrush limiting. If we added another FET to use the inductor to buck charge the super caps we would have to wait 10-15 seconds for a single board computer to wake up. I reside in Västerås, I have a facebook link on my profile page if you are nearby, at least StackOverflow frown upon using comments as a chat :D

Comment: You need to use @username or the user will not be notified of your reply here. Yes, the body diode will create a short circuit path for you, but there are even ICs for your specific purpose and you can stack two MOSFETs in series in opposite direction and have two modes of operation depending on current direction. Västerås is nearby :-)

Comment: @winny Bah, forgot the username part, defaulted to everyone commenting automatically being subscribed to the comment thread. Sadly, the FETs are connected on the wrong side of the inductor to buck charge the super caps. Once the high side FET pair opens the inductor current would have nowhere to go. The converter is currently configured to either boost the battery voltage up to a maximum of 150V, or buck the super cap voltage back down to the battery. I have tinkered with the circuit suggested by jonk and I think i can make it work for us. We will with our heatsink vs current for now.

Comment: "Are ballast resistors (R17, R8 and R5) required when using parallel current limiters as show below?" technically, not for the circuit itself, but at times, it is needed for inrush suppression if you have a lot of capacitance afterwards. When the ballast is really low in ohms though ( like 0.5 ohms) its going to act more like a fuse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ballast resistors are *not* required to help deal with part variations. The current control transistor should be thermally isolated from the TIP142 and from the current-measuring resistor, though. Also, you probably should include a soft-start capacitor in the circuit (or at least be aware of the idea in case it may help avoid damage to BJTs.) And you should include an emitter degeneration resistor for the control transistor to help equilibriate the currents.

---

I'm going to completely ignore your choice to divide this up into three current supplies and just look at the datasheet, instead. What I gather is that the die temperature should not exceed \$150\:^\circ\text{C}\$. I'll choose \$125\:^\circ\text{C}\$ to keep a margin. I'll also assume an ambient of \$25\:^\circ\text{C}\$, so the difference allowed is \$100\:^\circ\text{C}\$. Acccepting your worst-case \$58\:\text{V}\$ across the TIP142 itself, this means your situation must be \$I\le \frac{100\:^\circ\text{C}}{58\:\text{V}\cdot\left(R_{\theta \text{JC}}+R_{\theta \text{CA}}\right)}\$ where we already know that \$R_{\theta \text{JC}}=1\:\frac{^\circ\text{C}}{\text{W}}\$. Counting in the vagaries of mounting and the availability of heat sinks for these packages, I'm guessing that you cannot expect better than \$R_{\theta \text{CA}}=4\:\frac{^\circ\text{C}}{\text{W}}\$. This means \$I\le \frac{100\:^\circ\text{C}}{58\:\text{V}\cdot\left(1\:\frac{^\circ\text{C}}{\text{W}}+4\:\frac{^\circ\text{C}}{\text{W}}\right)}=430\:\text{mA}\$.

Or about \$25\:\text{W}\$ per section.

So already I have a problem with your choices. I think you need to plan on at least 10 of these sections. 12 would actually be the specification. But you are allowed to make some balancing decisions here. So I'd say anything at or above 10 sections would be advisable, given your desire for \$5\:\text{A}\$ total.

---

Variations in the TIP142 don't really matter that much, since you have a control transistor observing the current and making individual adjustments for each TIP142.

The current-control resistors will heat up and may account for a small shift in resistance (assuming you don't scrimp on its power rating.) But all of these current-control resistors are going to heat up together and I don't expect a large variation of resistance between them. So the variations in current supplied by each section, relative to these resistors, should be within the specification for the resistors, themselves.

So what matters here will be the variations between the control transistors. And this can be on the order of variations as if they were up to \$\pm 15\:^\circ\text{C}\$ different from each other, worst case. Or on the order of \$V_\text{BE}\$ variations of about \$\pm 30\:\text{mV}\$. Given an expected \$V_\text{BE}\approx 700\:\text{mV}\$ this could mean another 10% maximum variation between each section. Whether or not this is terribly important to you isn't a question I can answer. You could just leave it alone and live with it. But if you want to do something about it, you can add a small degeneration resistor into the emitter leg to provide a reasonably known "added voltage drop" to reduce the effective percent-variation between the sections.

This is why I said that the ballast resistors are *not* needed. That's a horrible waste of power and not nearly as effective, either.

---

Here's an example circuit I'd consider putting more time into:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPnbHsm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Assuming that \$Q_4\$ supplies \$10\:\text{mA}\$ at its collector (adjust \$R_3\$ to achieve this depending on your \$V_\text{CC}\$ power supply rail voltage), and assuming also that the TIP142 won't require more than \$500\:\mu\text{A}\$ into its base, then this means we have a reliable \$9.5\:\text{mA}\$ into \$Q_2\$'s collector and out its emitter into \$R_1\$. This makes the voltage drop across \$R_1\$ predictable at \$33\:\Omega\cdot 9.5\:\text{mA}\approx 260\:\text{mV}\$. Rounding things out, this places a \$1\:\text{V}\$ drop across \$R_2\$.

\$C_1\$ adds a soft-start component to this. (You might also add a \$27\:\text{k}\Omega\$ bleed-resistor across it -- not shown.) The current source \$Q_4\$ will have to charge up \$C_1\$ before the circuit can fully operate. I've set the timing here to about \$100\:\text{ms}\$. You can adjust this differently... or entirely avoid \$C_1\$, if you want.

I've used TO-220 BJTs for \$Q_3\$ and \$Q_4\$. Use whatever pair you want, but since one of them will dissipate up to a watt of power, the TO-220 package would be desired here. No heat sink needed. The package's \$R_{\theta \text{JA}}\$ should be good enough.

I believe the above circuit will provide a reliable section without the need for those wasteful ballast resistors you've added. It does so at the expense of a little more circuitry. But there is less waste, better balancing of the currents, and you now know that you need more than three sections, too.

---

You'd probably be much better off with a switcher design, though. You might check out this page: [Roman Black's constant current switching regulators](http://www.romanblack.com/smps/a05.htm).

---

### Added Note

Per your question about the current mirror:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fexwML.png)</sup>

I think you can see the buffering/base current compensation BJT that's been added: \$Q_5\$. This will handle the added base currents.

Comment: Thank you, yes it would probably be better to use a switcher instead. We might have to reevaluate our choice of what seemed to be a simple but wasteful solution. We shall see what we can do about heatsinking, but it does not look great. Maybe I can conjure up a control circuit that will allow the switcher to start before the single board computer and MCU have booted, at least that puts me back in digital territory :D. But with the low current we can expect to manage with this circuit it might even be faster if we use the the onboard computer to control a switcher. Again, thank you!

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that I can use multiple output transistors from the current mirror, each with their own ballast resistor (R4 & R5)? According to LTspice there is a very minor reduction in the mirrors output current if I add another leg to the mirror. So the current difference would be the resistor tolerance + a small part of transistor variations?

Comment: @Snellface Actually, you can just piggy-back one after another. But it is better then if you add a base current compensation/buffering BJT. You should be able to find an example on the web easily enough. You have plenty of voltage headroom so it should be fine to use.

Comment: @Snellface See the addition I made.

Comment: I added Q5 to my simulation. When the current limiting ends Q5 begins to draw a lot of current. Once the caps are fully charged Q5 consumes about 600mW per each additional output (Q7, Q8..).

Comment: @Snellface Hmm. I missed thinking about that point. Good catch. Once the capacitors charge, the current sources will saturate and require lots of base current which that BJT will try and supply. It needs a fold-back current limiter to it. Do you know how to design that? It can also tell you when things are charged, too, with a light I suppose. Or just stick a resistor in its collector and cheat that way. (I'll stick that into my example. Cheap and I don't have to think.)

Comment: I have looked quickly on foldback limiters, but as I understand it their purpose is more to limit overcurrent than limiting "normal" current. The current limiter will be bypassed by a FET after the super caps are charged, and will be charged even more by a boost converter afterwards. Our first idea was to just use a large power resistor, but since the charging current declines it takes a very long time to charge the super caps to the battery potential.

Comment: May I ask why your design wants such a long soft-start? A 10u cap seems to slow down the current rise with about 2-4ms, is there still a point in having a very short soft start? I also plan on cutting of the current mirrors ground connection once the circuit is bypassed, do you see any problem with that? Other than perhaps having to show down the FET turn-off? The FET would go between R3 and GND. I still don't quite see the point of Q5, but I would guess it's supposed to prevent the decline in charge current once the super caps are getting more and more charged? Boosting pass BJT base current?

Comment: @Snellface No particular reason for the soft start time period. I just picked something. I mostly wanted to point out that it was possible and that it may reduce stress on parts when you turn on the power. But you don't have to do it if you don't want to. Or select a smaller or larger capacitor value. It's up to you.

Comment: @Snellface Regarding Q5, I was merely addressing the fact that you noticed a minor reduction in simulation as more stages were added. Q5 supplies the extra base curents from its collector, bypassing having them go through \$R_3\$ and thereby reducing the collector current in \$Q_3\$. But feel free to avoid it and accept the slight reduction. No need to worry too much, I suppose. And sure. You can remove the current mirror's set-current by just opening that up with a FET to ground or else by just bypassing Q3's collector to the positive rail.